# Inject image/svg/whatever in an angular template with cache hash handling

Tags: html, angular, typescript, caching, require

Having an assets folder with :

- /assets/images/image1.png
- /assets/svg/svg1.svg

How to include it in an HTML template (not in a CSS file) in order to have angular/webpack to automatically enable cache-busting on it (transforming automaticallt `assets/images/image1.jpg` to `assets/images/image1-4d5678xc0v987654v.jpg`?
The goal is to handle cache and refresh it soon ASAP when an existing file gets updated.

With webpack, I used to do a :

```
<img src="<%=require("./assets/img/image1.jpg")%>" />
```

The only solution I found with angular is requiring all my images in the .ts file but it's quite a pain to do :

```
const image1src = require(`../assets/images/image1.jpg`);
class Component {
    image1 = image1src; // contains image1-4d5678xc0v987654v.jpg
}
// and in template : <img [src]="image2" />
```

Is there something simplier ?

- ps: I don't want to handle a query paremeter or custom name myself
- pps: I don't want to inject these files through CSS (and I know it works when files are getting injected by css)
- ppps: using a PWA is not an option in my case

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created a pipe for this so I don't need to create variables inside a component as you did.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
   name: 'imgURL'
})

export class ImgURLPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: string): string {
        return require('../../../images/' + value); // specify here a correct src to your folder with images
    }

}
```

To make the require works inside components or pipes, add this to your typings:

```
declare var require: {
<T>(path: string): T;
(paths: string[], callback: (...modules: any[]) => void): void;
ensure: (
    paths: string[],
    callback: (require: <T>(path: string) => T) => void
) => void;
};
```

Inside a template, it looks like this:

```
<img [src]="'myImage.png' | imgURL">
```

Remember to add a declaration of the pipe to your module.

Answer (score -1):

are you using angular-cli?
Check this article, it explains how to manage the assets with angular-cli: https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2017/09/manage-assets-and-static-files-with.html

Other solution would be to use css, eg:
  background: url('../assets/fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.svg')

Comment: Thanks but your article didn't help. Copying assets this way prevents cache busting totally. Css is an option i mentioned but my question excludes it.